# Deleting Record in MS Access Form With Button

Tags: ms-access

Recently started learning Access and I'm a bit stuck on deleting records within a form. I have a list with the following code:

```
Private Sub lstPickList_AfterUpdate()
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
rst.FindFirst "OrderID=" & lstPickList.Column(0) & ""
If rst.NoMatch Then
    MsgBox "The selected record can not be displayed." _
        & "To display this record, you must first turn off record filtering.", _
        vbInformation
Else
    Me.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark
End If
Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```

And a button that I would like to use to delete whatever Order is currently selected on the list. The "DeleteRecord" macro just gives me a "The command or action 'DeleteRecord' isn't available now." error. Searching has given me a bunch of code that hasn't worked for me at all.

Comment: Code runs a form search depending on selected record in list if you change else statement to: `Me.RecordSet.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark`. Simply delete after search: `DoCmd.RunCommnd acCmdDeleteRecord`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete directly from the clone:

```
If rst.NoMatch Then
    MsgBox "The selected record can not be displayed." _
        & "To display this record, you must first turn off record filtering.", _
        vbInformation
Else
    rst.Delete
End If
```